# Remove Product Categories title from woocommerce pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Does anybody know how to remove (or hide) the Product Categories title on woocommerce pages?

It's using the h4 font settings in theme.php, these are also used for other element titles that I do not want to hide/remove. Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Comment: check the widget section it have some widget related to woo-commerce category list

Answer (score 2):

In your theme functions.php add:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_show_page_title', create_function('$result', 'return false;'), 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in your style.css file:-

```
.sidepanel.woocommerce.widget_product_categories h4 {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why down vote? It hides the title 'Product Categories' on the right sidebar.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding! where exactly do I paste the code?

Comment: You need to paste this code in your theme's style.css file. It can be located in your web server directory at `/wp-content/themes/{theme-name}/style.css`